# How to append blade template in panel-body

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5

I created a two panel one for the user's options and the second panel is the transition of the panel. As you can see below I have a group of buttons every-time the user click the buttons the left panel will changed it's content every-time it clicks. But it won't work if I click on the buttons.

[image]

I used `empty()` so it will be empty first the `panel-body` on my left container after that I will append in the `panel-body` section

Master page below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "{{ URL::asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "{{ URL::asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>

<script>

    $(document).on("click", "#curriculum", function ()
    {
        $.get("curriculumOption.blade.php", function (data)
        {
            $("#rightContainer").empty();
            $("#rightContainer").append(data);
            alert("This is curriculum");
        });
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#subjects", function ()
    {
        $.get("subjectsOption.blade.php", function (data)
        {   
            $("#rightContainer").empty();
            $("#rightContainer").append(data);
            alert("This is subjects");
        });
    });

</script>

</head>
<body>
@include ('layouts.navigation.user')
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-3">

            <div class = "panel panel-default">

                <div class = "panel-body" style = "height: 300px">

                    <div class = "btn-group" data-toggle = "buttons">

                        <label class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg">
                        <input type = "checkbox" id = "curriculum"> Curriculum
                        </label><br>

                        <label class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg">
                            <input type = "checkbox" id = "subjects"> Subjects
                        </label><br>


                    </div>



                </div>

            </div>

        </div>




        <div class="col-lg-6">

            <div class = "panel panel-default">

                <div class = "panel-body" id = "rightContainer" style = "height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll;">

                    //RIGHT CONTAINER

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

**OPTIONS:**

- subjectsOption
- curriculumOption

**subjectsOption.blade.php**

```
<div class = "btn-group" data-toggle = "buttons">

    <label class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg">
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "subjectList"> Subject List
    </label><br>

    <label class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg">
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "createSubjects"> Create Subjects
    </label><br>

<div>
```

**curriculumOption.blade.php**

```
<div class = "btn-group" data-toggle = "buttons">

    <label class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg">
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "curriculumList"> Curriculum List
    </label><br>

    <label class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg">
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "createCurriculum"> Create Curriculum
    </label><br>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel Blade Template, or PHP file inside the /resources/views inside Laravel framework is not accessible using URL directly, to be precise, everything under /resources folder and even all other folders except /public, are not accessible. Only public folder can be accessed directly by using URL in laravel framework. You must notice that the view inside resources folder can only be returned after come from route -> controller -> view to be simple.

Thus, this part of your code

```
$(document).on("click", "#curriculum", function ()
{
    $.get("curriculumOption.blade.php", function (data)
    {
        $("#rightContainer").empty();
        $("#rightContainer").append(data);
        alert("This is curriculum");
    });
});

$(document).on("click", "#subjects", function ()
{
    $.get("subjectsOption.blade.php", function (data)
    {   
        $("#rightContainer").empty();
        $("#rightContainer").append(data);
        alert("This is subjects");
    });
});
```

is trying to access your server in certain URL. lets take example your domain is test.laravel.dev and you are in root of your domain (in your browser you can see http://test.laravel.dev), and you run these script there. It means that you are trying to do AJAX request to url http://test.laravel.dev/curriculumOption.blade.php and http://test.laravel.dev/subjectOption.blade.php. What will happens? this will try to find route in your routes.php file, looking for "/curriculumOption.blade.php" or "/subjectOption.blade.php" which i am sure it's not exists there. what you can do is, if you still need the blade template to be processed before returning as AJAX response, you can make it like this:

**routes.php**

```
Route::get("/curriculumOption","CurriculumOptionController@show");
```

**CurriculumOptionController.php**

```
public function show()
{
     //do your things here
     return view("curriculumOption");
}
```

with the curriculumOption.blade.php is under /resources/views folder, and change your ajax request to:

```
$(document).on("click", "#curriculum", function ()
{
    $.get("/curriculumOption", function (data)
    {
        $("#rightContainer").empty();
        $("#rightContainer").append(data);
        alert("This is curriculum");
    });
});
```

This will work, please try and ask if have any other problem.

**Explanation #1**
Due to some security reason and also as a feature for laravel, most of the folders except public cannot be accessed without PHP preprocessor. When you are making a request in browser, the HTTP request is being sent to your browser to the server. in this case, if you make get request, you dont pass any other additional form parameters to server. Server read the request URL from your browser and then there are some server configuration in how are they going to pass the parameter to PHP preprocessor. These configuration is set in .htaccess file for apache HTTP server, nginx configuration for NGINX, and web.config for IIS server. You can notice that the .htaccess file is included in your **/public** folder of laravel project and the **/public** folder is the default for your domain, lets say your domain is test.laravel.dev, then **test.laravel.dev** is equal to **/public** and **test.laravel.dev/index.php** is refering to **/public/index.php** file. The rest that can be put in **/public** usually are css, javascript, and image files. Templates, Controller, Routes, etc are not accessible from URL. They are being managed by the framework. **/resource** folder is not accessible for security reason also. The only way is to access it from route or controller. **If you dont define what to do with a certain URI, laravel framework will not give a proper response which is most likely erorr**. Your /management/curriculumOption.blade.php can't be accessed simply because you dont have a route with

```
   Route::get("/management/curriculumOption.blade.php"/, .....)
```

even though i dont think you can put .blade.php in the parameters also, but worth to try. There are only 2 options(need citation) to access certain URL to be responded in Laravel:

1. Define it in routes.php
2. put it in public folder

Comment: I already do this method and it's working. I'm still thinking why it won't show in my URL the blade template that I currently have for example. `/management/curriculumOption.blade.php` this won't show if I clicked on of the buttons. :)

Comment: vote up also please for my reputation :P , ok i put my explanation in updated answer since the comment is limited in explanation #1.

Comment: I tried to follow as what you said. The `Route::get("/management/curriculumOption.blade.php"/, .....)` won't work on me it doesn't append the `curriculumOption` when I try this? Any help?

Comment: you can't and better don't do it, don't make something like extension in routing. please remember that this is no longer directory-based simple php. this is already a framework that protect the directory access thus we have to go through webserver and framework's routing. what you want is hide the real name of your files, but yet still put it descriptive enough to be recognized. instead of using full name "curriculumOption.blade.php", just use "curriculum-name" in route. Other programmer won't really know your real file name and your site not be easier to be attacked(security consent)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you out checkbox in label. I have just remove the checkbox and add id to labels.

Add insert php file data using html()function.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "{{ URL::asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "{{ URL::asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>

<script>

    $(document).on("click", "#curriculum", function ()
    {
        $.get("curriculumOption.blade.php", function (data)
        {
            //$("#rightContainer").empty();
            $("#rightContainer").html(data);
            alert("This is curriculum");
        });
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#subjects", function ()
    {
        $.get("subjectsOption.blade.php", function (data)
        {   
            //$("#rightContainer").empty();
            $("#rightContainer").html(data);
            alert("This is subjects");
        });
    });

</script>

</head>
<body>
@include ('layouts.navigation.user')
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-3">

            <div class = "panel panel-default">

                <div class = "panel-body" style = "height: 300px">

                    <div class = "btn-group" data-toggle = "buttons">

                        <label class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg"  id = "curriculum">
                        Curriculum
                        </label><br>

                        <label class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg" id = "subjects">
                            Subjects
                        </label><br>


                    </div>



                </div>

            </div>

        </div>




        <div class="col-lg-6">

            <div class = "panel panel-default">

                <div class = "panel-body" id = "rightContainer" style = "height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll;">

                    //RIGHT CONTAINER

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```